# Can I route wire on the right side of this panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

All existing wires to my service panel go from the left side. I want to add an EVSE circuit at slots 3 and 4. Can I do it per the first picture below routing the wire from the right side and making a loop at the top? I want to do it this way for 2 reasons:

1. gauge 6 wires are thick and left side is busy
2. I want to clamp the subpanel and EVSE load together for load shedding the EVSE so the direction of the current needs to match both of these circuits. Putting it like below will allow me to clamp the subpanel and EVSE load either next to slot 1 and 2 or above slot 1. I'll likely have to move the subpanel breaker higher up to get some slack in the wires to give me space for the CT clamps.

[image: Text]

[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Edit: I ended up wiring it as my sketch above. See final photo below. Please let me know if this violates anything before I have the city inspection in a couple of months.

[image: Text]

Comment: A couple of _months_ to get an inspection??? Wow... I'll quit complaining that it takes 2 calls to get my inspector out in a couple of days!

Comment: Possible concern about your black tape, NEC 200.7.C(1) says "shall encircle the insulation" but I'm seeing more like a black stripe than a wrap here.

Comment: The couple of months wait is on me. Typically the city has availability within a week. I need more time because I also want to self install a water heater and fix the dryer circuit in the same permit. Thanks for the pointer to NEC 200.7.C(1). I'll apply a second black stripe so that no white is visible.